# Windows Phone: how to save a log of user actions?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to save a log of whatever user is doing in my application. For example, if user clicks  specific button or Icon I want to record it. How can I achieve that in windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

I would use google analytics for this.
http://devatheart.com/2012/09/02/analytics-for-windows-phone-nuget-to-rule-them-all/